# Sharing between safari and the native app

Tags: safari, native, sharing

I know that From a native app I can `openURL:` to open Safari and then in the javascript, use `URL-Scheme` of the app to open and send any data back.

I want to know if this sharing is possible without actually opening the safari - Any sort of common storage between safari and native app - cookies or client side storage or keychain - anything?

And If there's no such common storage and safari has to be opened - Then, Is there any little customization I can do to safari such as hiding location-bar/tool-bar without having user to Add it to the Home Screen and open it like a web app?

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. As all the apps are sandboxed. Doesn't look like there is any official way around it.